# How to replay event which triggered by server in performance-test (Loadrunner, socket, C/S)?

Tags: c#, sockets, testing, performance-testing

**Precondition:** I was doing performance test with a pharmacy management system.
This system is:

- based on C/S structure
- developed by .Net using WCF which means it's clients communicate with server by socket
- using MySQL as database

And one of it's functions is dispensing prescriptions. It has five clients (which called "Window1" to "Window5") and one server. It's workflow is like this:

1. Server receives prescriptions from HIS (Hospital information system) and generates tasks;
2. After one patient check-in, server sends that task to one window which is relatively idle;
3. The window receives, fulfills that task and returns the task status to server;
4. Server updates the task status to HIS.

From this procedure, it's clear that the client do nothing until it receives tasks from server. Which means the clients is driven by server.

**My attempt:**

- Tools: Loadrunner
- Protocol: Windows Sockets

I record one time dispensing (a task of one prescription including one medication) in a client ("Window1"), but disappointed to find that it can not replay. Guess it's because the "buf" (my client received from server including several variables like "Task ID", "Encounter ID", etc. which uniquely identifies the task) can not be received in replay.

**Question:** So, how can I emulate client behavior when the events is triggered not by client but by server ? Thanks for reading this, any advice is a big help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no experience in Winsock, which is akin to picking fly scat out of ground pepper, then you would be well served to consider the .net virtual user type, the Citrix virtual user or the RDP virtual user.  Lastly you could also consider the GUI virtual user (last resort as this would be state of the art for performance testing in 1993)